# Overloading a function for more than one API level

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to overload a function (`WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` to be specific). My targetSdkVersion is 24 and minSdkVersion is 15. The values are chosen intentionally because this app is an "experiment" and will be part of a bigger one with said target and minimum SDK versions.
I have already read [Supporting different platforms](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html) on developer.android.com. According to the documentation, previously mentioned function has two different signatures. One with the parameter types `WebView` and `WebRessourceRequest` and the other one with `WebView`and `String`. The later one was deprecated with api level 24.

So my question is: Which one should I override and use? The newer one (with the request object) to ensure long term compatibility or the older, deprecated one which might be removed in future APIs? Or can and should I override both?

**Edit**
So I need something like this pseudocode:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    if(**API level of device is higher than 24**){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebRessourceRequest request){...}
    }else{
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){...}
    }
}
```

Comment: Methods from higherSDK's are not available for lowerSDK's...

Comment: You can override both and depending upon the API level of the user, call the respective one.

Comment: @PrerakSola And the older one (which does not know about the function with request as parameter) won't break?

Answer (score 1):

You should support both implementations to target the most amount of your app's clients:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        WebResourceRequest webResourceRequest = new WebResourceRequest() {
            @Override
            public Uri getUrl() {
                return url;
            }

            /*Implement other methods*/
        };
        webViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView, webResourceRequest);
    } else {
        webViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView, url);
    }
```

**EDIT:**
If you are overriding WebViewClient, then there is no need to worry. On older devices only deprecated function will be called. Those devices don't know anything about new function.
New devices will call the new function.

Comment: This seems to be the right direction, but I need something a bit different. I updated the question to make it clear.

Comment: If there is no appcompat version of this functionality, this is the correct way to support multiple APIs